# android-binding: onclick depend on variable

Tags: android-databinding

I need when `isFavorite`  is true then when click then call `onClickSubscribe()` else call `onClickUnsubscribe()`.

In my fragment:

```
  @Override
    public void onClickSubscribe() {

    }
```

In my xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

        <data>

            <import type="android.view.View" />

            <variable
                name="handler"
                type="SubscribeBrandDialogFragment" />

        </data>


         <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subscribeTextView"
                android:layout_width="185dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp" 
                android:onClick="@{handler.isFavorite ? handler.onClickSubscribe() : handler.onClickUnsubscribe()}"
                android:text="@{handler.isFavorite ? @string/unsubscribe : @string/subscribe}"/>

    </layout>
```

But I get error:

```
e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter type void on android.widget.TextView.
file:res\layout\subscribe_brand_dialog.xml
loc:100:31 - 100:108
****\ data binding error ****

    at android.databinding.tool.processing.Scope.assertNoError(Scope.java:112)
```

Comment: You are getting error related to `SubscribeBrandDialogFragment` and you did not show that here?

Comment: I update my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:onClick' with parameter
> type void on android.widget.TextView

### What does this say? Exactly this is problem!

If you don't write **`()->`** in your onClick then you have to give your View type as first parameter in method.

### Solution

Change onClick line to below.

```
android:onClick="@{handler.isFavorite ? handler::onClickSubscribe : handler::onClickUnsubscribe}"
```

And set `TextView` as first parameter of `onClickSubscribe` & `onClickUnsubscribe` like.

```
void onClickSubscribe (TextView tv) {
...
}
```

& same for `onClickUnsubscribe`

All done!

### I like shortcuts, so here is Tip

Make a common method with `Boolean`.

```
void onSubscribe(boolean isSubscribe){
   if(isSubscribe){}
   else {}
}
```

and call it like

```
android:onClick="@{() -> handler.onSubscribe(handler.isFavorite)}"
```

*So your two methods are reduced to 1.*

**If you need to pass any other value just change parameter of `onSubscribe`. and pass from xml.**

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :

```
android:onClick="@{()->handler.isFavorite ? handler.onClickSubscribe() : handler.onClickUnsubscribe()}"
```

do no forget `()->` at first